# Yii2 ExpandRowColumn not working with ScrollPager

Tags: php, jquery, yii2

I have this below code and when I click to expand the row then its working for first page and when its scroll down and when load the next page onward then expand not working.

```
            <?php
            echo GridView::widget([
                "dataProvider" => $dataProvider,
                "filterSelector" => "select[name='per-page']",
                'floatHeader' => true,
                'floatHeaderOptions' => [
                    'scrollingTop' => '50',
                    'floatContainerClass' => "float_table_header"
                ],
                "layout" => getGridLayout(),
                "tableOptions" => ["class" => "table table-striped task-management-table"],
                "columns" => [
                        [
                        'class' => 'kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn',
                        'width' => '50px',
                        'detailRowCssClass' => 'detailRowCssClass',
                        'detailUrl' => Url::to(['test/test1']),
                        'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                            return GridView::ROW_COLLAPSED;
                        },
                        'headerOptions' => ['class' => 'kartik-sheet-style'],
                        'expandOneOnly' => false
                    ],
                ],
               
                'pager' => [
                    'class' => ScrollPager::className(),
                    'container' => '.grid-view tbody',
                    'item' => 'tr',
                    'paginationSelector' => '.grid-view .pagination',
                    'triggerTemplate' => '<tr class="ias-trigger"><td colspan="100%" style="text-align: center"><a style="cursor: pointer">{text}</a></td></tr>',
                    'enabledExtensions' => [
                        ScrollPager::EXTENSION_SPINNER,
                        //ScrollPager::EXTENSION_NONE_LEFT,
                        ScrollPager::EXTENSION_PAGING,
                    ],
                ],
            ]);
            ?>
        <?php //ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```